# Should routes be devoid of logic?

Tags: routes, design-patterns, server, controller, backend

I'm trying to calibrate my balance of router logic and controller logic. I'm hoping to get some insight on what logic should be doable in a routes especially in terms of testability.

For example, my controller has methods akin to:

1. `CheckUserExists`
2. `GetUserInfo`
3. `ChangeUserData`

In my route, a basic get request would be:

1. `Controller.CheckUserExists`
2. `Controller.GetUserInfo`

Or if updating a unique field, like an email the route would call:

1. `Controller.CheckUserExists` with the new email
2. Either:

   a. Throw an error if it already exists

   b. `Controller.ChangeUserData` with the new email

Testing the controller in this case is straightforward, and testing the routes in E2E tests is doable.

But is the route doing too much? Should it just pass off the query data to a single controller method like a black box and respond with the response/error?

Testing wise it would be simpler since there's no need to mock the router, but it would also mean having a controller method for each endpoint for the router to call. Is this done in practice?